# C# Split Times into Hour Blocks

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, timestamp

I am in need of some assistance in getting 2 datetimes to split into the hour intervals between them.

This is working with 'pay' data, so it needs to be very accurate. I need to take clockin and clockout, and split them into hour intervals.

**Example:**

clockin = 5/25/2011 1:40:56PM

clockout = 5/25/2011 6:22:12PM

**I need that to look like:**

5/25/2011 1:40:56PM

5/25/2011 2:00:00PM

5/25/2011 3:00:00PM

5/25/2011 4:00:00PM

5/25/2011 5:00:00PM

5/25/2011 6:00:00PM

5/25/2011 6:22:12PM

I then plan to check those times against a 'differential' table to see fi they should have a new paycode. But I'll worry about the paycode later.

Any help splitting out the times?  Prefer C#, but I also have access to MSSQL2000 (which is where we pull the original times)

Comment: I'm unclear as to what the hours variable represents. It looks like an array that represents the start or end of a timespan that is up to one hour. Is that what your looking for?

Generally, it seems like a loop using DateTime.AddHour would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: @Tobias I cleaned up the question and removed the hours variable while you were replying :).  As for the add hour, I suppose I can do that, the only issue is I have to add these times together eventually. So I almost need to convert them to minutes instead of what I suggest above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var hours = new List<DateTime>();
hours.Add(clockin);

var next = new DateTime(clockin.Year, clockin.Month, clockin.Day,
                        clockin.Hour, 0, 0, clockin.Kind);

while ((next = next.AddHours(1)) < clockout)
{
    hours.Add(next);
}
hours.Add(clockout);
```

Comment: Copying the DateTimeKind is a smart move indeed! I'll include that in my answer as well.

Comment: I ended up using this route. Although Markus Olssons answer is more flexible, this was so simple I couldn't resist using it. Should allow my teammates to understand it as well, and they are novice.

Answer (score 13):

How about something like this?

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetWorkingHourIntervals(DateTime clockIn, DateTime clockOut)
{
    yield return clockIn;

    DateTime d = new DateTime(clockIn.Year, clockIn.Month, clockIn.Day, clockIn.Hour, 0, 0, clockIn.Kind).AddHours(1);

    while (d < clockOut)
    {
        yield return d;
        d = d.AddHours(1);
    }

    yield return clockOut;
}
```

This uses [iterator blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but it could easily be rewritten to return a list instead.

Example use:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var clockIn = new DateTime(2011, 5, 25, 13, 40, 56);
    var clockOut = new DateTime(2011, 5, 25, 18, 22, 12);

    var hours = GetWorkingHourIntervals(clockIn, clockOut);

    foreach (var h in hours)
        Console.WriteLine(h);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
2011-05-25 13:40:56
2011-05-25 14:00:00
2011-05-25 15:00:00
2011-05-25 16:00:00
2011-05-25 17:00:00
2011-05-25 18:00:00
2011-05-25 18:22:12
```

**Update**: [LukeH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230143/c-split-times-into-hour-blocks/6230244#6230244) was clever enough to suggest that you should also copy the DateTimeKind. This is indeed a smart move if you're planning on converting the datetimes to/from local time later on.

Comment: This answer is excellent, and I wish I could give 2 answers out. This is very flexible. However, for my specific needs on this question, I went with another answer mainly due to my team. But this answer is great!

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this should work:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetHourlyBreakdown(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var hours = new List<DateTime>();
    hours.Add(startDate);
    var currentDate = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day, startDate.Hour, 0, 0).AddHours(1);
    while(currentDate < endDate)
    {
        hours.Add(new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, currentDate.Hour, 0, 0));
        currentDate = currentDate.AddHours(1);
    }
    hours.Add(endDate);
    return hours;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetIntervals(DateTime clockIn, DateTime clockOut)
{
    yield return clockIn;

    clockIn = clockIn.AddHours(1).Subtract(clockIn.TimeOfDay).AddHours(clockIn.Hour);

    for (DateTime dt = clockIn; dt < clockOut; dt = dt.AddHours(1))
        yield return dt;

    yield return clockOut;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
    foreach (DateTime dt in GetIntervals(DateTime.Parse("5/25/2011 1:40:56PM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), DateTime.Parse("5/25/2011 6:22:12PM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
```