# How To Set Time Interval using SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to make the report in which the time interval is minutes and i have the start time & end time  and want to have the time interval between two times.

For example.

Start Time:- 8:00PM END TIME:- 16:00PM

Table Structure may be like this.

```
S.no ---------------------------Time Interval

1--------------------------------8:00 AM - 8:10 AM(ENTRY STARTS)

2--------------------------------8:10 AM- 8:20 AM

3------------------------------- 8:20 AM - 8:30 AM


Nth-----------------------------3:50PM - 4:00 PM(LAST ENTRY FOR
 REPORT)
```

How can i do this using on SQL query and i want to use it in Asp.Net GridView?

For example.

**RE TABLE STRUCTURE**

**using the below data now iam trying to put the no of keys between the start time of workdatetime and last of this workdatetime/**

Logic is SAme as PREVIOUS but unable to put the NO OF KEYS between the Time Interval.
I wan to show the structure same as above only add one column No of keys with respect to the time interval/

WorkdateTime    ************    NoOfKeys

16:52:04    ************    54

16:52:06    ************    0

16:52:07    ************    2

16:52:25    ************    0

16:52:26    ************    0

16:52:35    ************    0

16:52:35    ************    0

16:53:15    ************    0

16:53:55    ************    0

16:54:28    ************    11

16:54:35    ************    0

16:55:15    ************    0

16:55:55    ************    0

16:56:35    ************    0

16:57:15    ************    0

16:57:28    ************    103

16:57:55    ************    0

16:58:35    ************    0

16:58:39    ************    2

16:59:09    ************    19

16:59:15    ************    0

16:59:42    ************    40

16:59:43    ************    2

16:59:55    ************    0

17:00:35    ************    0

17:01:15    ************    0

17:01:35    ************    4

17:01:55    ************    0

17:02:35    ************    0

17:03:15    ************    0

17:03:55    ************    0

17:03:58    ************    2

17:04:24    ************    3

17:04:35    ************

17:05:15    ************    0

17:05:40    ************    0

17:05:46    ************    14

17:05:47    ************    0

17:05:50    ************    2

17:06:30    ************    0

17:06:37    ************    1

17:07:10    ************    0

17:07:50    ************    0

17:08:12    ************    1

17:08:30    ************    0

17:09:10    ************    0

17:09:27    ************    42

17:09:50    ************    0

Comment: So what have you done so far and what is it that you have a problem with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Split Times into Hour Blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230143/c-sharp-split-times-into-hour-blocks)

Comment: i want the data look like this . when i input the start time and endtime only , dynamically the interval is created as i show above

Comment: the duplicate link splits based on hours so you could just modify the code to split into 10 minute intervals

Comment: ok i got it, accutaly can i adjust the two time simultaneously just like i show above eg.(8:00 AM - 8:10 AM) Hmmm

BUT THE MAIN  THING IS THAT ARTICLE IS WRITTEN IN C# NOT IN SQL

Comment: it can be done using CTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @Start time
declare @end time
declare @request int

set @Start = '08:00:00'
set @end = '16:00:00'
set @request = 1

;with Dates as (
    select @request as reqId,@Start as reqDate
    union all
    select reqId+1,DATEADD(MINUTE,10,reqDate) from Dates
    where reqDate < @end
)
select reqId,convert(varchar(8),reqDate,100)+'-'+convert(varchar(8),DATEADD(MINUTE,10,reqDate),100) "Time Interval" from Dates
```

Use this for ur reports

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DateDiff](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, '2000-01-01 08:00:00' , '2000-01-01 16:00:00');
```

Return the difference/interval in seconds. Divide by 60 to get minutes, and divide by 60 again to get hours.

Since you are only using the time component, you can set the datepart to whatever you like.

EDIT:

Since I misread the question, maybe you want something like this:

```
DateTime startAt = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01, 8, 0, 0);
DateTime endAt = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01, 16, 0, 0);

for (DateTime date = startAt; date < endAt; date = date.AddMinutes(10))
{
    // create something with this interval
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Interval start: {0}, Interval End: {1}", date.ToString("HH:mm"), date.AddMinutes(10).ToString("HH:mm")));
}
```

Just use the start date and end date and loop through it with 10min intervals.

Comment: that will show the difference between 2 dates, not split it into 10 min intervals over rows as asked in the question

Comment: @user3345235 See my updated answer. It is in C#, but may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `CTE`

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndTime DATETIME

SELECT @StartDate = '8:00 PM'
SELECT @EndTime = '9:00 PM'


;WITH time_cte(StartTime, EndTime) AS
(
   SELECT @StartDate StartTime, DATEADD(mi, 10, @StartDate) EndTime

   UNION ALL

   SELECT EndTime, DATEADD(mi, 10, EndTime)  FROM time_cte
   WHERE EndTime < @EndTime

)  
SELECT * FROM time_cte
```

Check its working at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0575/16)